# How to Convert File into a list in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, python-import

I'm trying to make a list from an import file but can't get it to work properly.

```
import csv

fileName = "/home/bluebird/Desktop/Deck"
# the file is this
# A,A,@,@,$,$,&,&,!,!,H,H,Z,Z,W,W

f = open(fileName, 'r')
reader = csv.reader(f)
allRows = [row for row in reader]

print(allRows)
size = len(allRows)
print(size)
```

The result I get is:

```
[['A', 'A', '@', '@', '$', '$', '&', '&', '!', '!', 'H', 'H','Z', 'Z', 'W', 'W']]
1
```

But I'm trying to get:

```
['A', 'A', '@', '@', '$', '$', '&', '&', '!', '!', 'H', 'H', 'Z', 'Z', 'W', 'W']
16
```

Comment: Does `allRows = [row for row in reader][0]` work?

Comment: I was just about to say, it looks like you have a list in a list

Comment: If you want me to explain it in more detail, just let me know

Answer (score 2):

The `line`:

```
reader = csv.reader(f)
```

will `read` in the `file` and return a `reader` `object`. Instead of using a `list-comprehension` to convert it to a `list` of each `row` of `data`, you can just pass it into `list()` which is more Pythonic:

```
allRows = list(reader)
```

Now, `allRows` is a `list` of `lists` (`rows`).

As you only have one `row` in your `file`, `allRows` in this case is:

```
[['A', 'A', '@', '@', '$', '$', '&', '&', '!', '!', 'H', 'H', 'Z', 'Z', 'W', 'W']]
```

And the `length` of `allRows` (`len(allRows)`) is going to be `1`- as there is just one `row` in the `list`.

If you want to extract the first `row`, you can take the first `element` (`row`) from the `list` with:

```
firstRow = allRows[0]
```

then if you do:

```
print(firstRow)
```

you will get:

```
['A', 'A', '@', '@', '$', '$', '&', '&', '!', '!', 'H', 'H', 'Z', 'Z', 'W', 'W']
```

and:

```
print(len(firstRow))
```

will give you:

```
16
```

As you want **:)**

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have a list in a list.

A quick fix would be

```
allRows = allRows[0]
```